# Timing which is faster to add to a TreeSet and a HashSet?

Tags: java

I have a TreeSet and a HashSet and want to print out both the times of how long it takes for a .txt file to be added to both of them.
As of right now, I am only able to record the time for both, any guidance or assistance.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Timer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Calendar    startTime    =    Calendar.getInstance();
    Set<String> hSet = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> tSet = new TreeSet<String>();

    try{
        File in = new File("C:\\Users\\Ceri\\Desktop\\war-and-peace.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
        while(s.hasNext()){
            String temp = s.next();
            hSet.add(temp);
            tSet.add(temp);
        }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException    e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

    Calendar    endTime    =    Calendar.getInstance();
    double    consumedTime    =    (endTime.getTimeInMillis()    -
    startTime.getTimeInMillis())    /    1000.0;
    System.out.println("Consumed    time:"        +    consumedTime);

}
```

}

Comment: *"As of right now, I am only able to record the time for both, any guidance or assistance."* Um....do them one at a time? E.g., do them separately?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that tests the time a `Set` takes, then call it with each kind of set:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Timer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        test("HashSet time: " , new HashSet<String>());
        test("TreeSet time: " , new TreeSet<String>());
    }

    private void test(String label, Set set) {

        Calendar    startTime    =    Calendar.getInstance();

        try{
            File in = new File("C:\\Users\\Ceri\\Desktop\\war-and-peace.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
            while(s.hasNext()){
                String temp = s.next();
                set.add(temp);  // <==== Note
            }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException    e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

        // (I didn't try to fix this truly bizarre indentation / line breaking)
        Calendar    endTime    =    Calendar.getInstance();
        double    consumedTime    =    (endTime.getTimeInMillis()    -
        startTime.getTimeInMillis())    /    1000.0;
        System.out.println(label        +    consumedTime);
    }
}
```

Other ways you might improve it:

1. Read the file **once**, before adding the data to either `Set`, so that you're not washing out the `Set` performance information with file performance information
2. Have the function return the elapsed time and display the delta
3. Call the function several times so it's not just doing each one once, and track averages / worst example / best example

...and so on.